# Application error while displaying images inside Webview

Tags: android, cordova

I am creating an android app which displays all the images for a particular user.

I am currently preparing a string on my server (which is actually html code generated dynamically) and then returning this string to my android app. Then the app loads this retrieved string into the Webview. (This string actually contains the absolute urls for the images)

However, for the first couple of times when the app starts and tries to load the images, it actually crashes. Afterwards, it loads the images faster and doesn't crash. I don't understand why this happens? Can anybody explain me the reason for the same.

Also, what it the best way to display a list of images (somewhat gridview type ) in an android app?

Logcat details when the crash happens:

```
04-26 10:30:09.972: INFO/System.out(4265): onReceivedError: Error code=-6 Description=The connection to the server was unsuccessful. URL=http://myworkingurl.com
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the logcat to identify the problem as well as some code where the program crashes.

Comment: The code does not crash. The crash happens only during the first couple of app starts. Then onwards, the app works fine.

Comment: post the logcat when the app crash

Comment: Added the logcat details in the question. Please refer the same and let me know if you can help with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may be in your mobile's network as it is too slow to get some url.
May be this code can help you

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 50000);
```

Comment: ok, now I am not getting the application error... can you tell me the reason why I was getting that error?